# C# Random Numbers

Tags: c#

Ok, So Im using  `int indexSelector = RandomNumber(1, 14);` to create a random number and pull the matching index out of an array. But it seems to only be calling 3 or 4 numbers. Like the items being pulled out are very similar.

Whats going on?

Comment: What is this `RandomNumber` function? There's no such function in the BCL so don't expect us knowing it what it does and why it returns the same numbers.

Comment: Can you give a full code listing including your `RandomNumber` method

Comment: RandomNumber is not a good name for a method. You should at least name it "GetRandomNumber"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you are calling a function which re-creates a Random object on each call.
Don't re-create your Random object on each function call.

So do something like this:

```
private Random random = new Random();
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
  return random.Next(min, max); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your random variable static:

```
static Random random = new Random();
```

Comment: Making it static will not make a difference if it's constructed "every" time the RandomNumber is called. static readonly and you're making a difference

Comment: @Rune: there is an initializing instance, we may assume that that is not getting replaced every time.

Comment: Be aware that the methods Random class are not thread-safe, so using it as a static variable will require locking.

Comment: @Henk yes i'm sure that's the point I simply ment it would be good to point it out especially since a likely cause to OPs problem is recreation so refactoring the _declaration_ alone wont help. Furthermore the code might as well show intend by the use of readonly

Comment: This is dangerous, since it's easy the access `random` from multiple threads now. Making it threadstatic is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Per Brian's suggestion, define your `Random` object somewhere where it won't be recreated:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

And use this to get the number:

```
int indexSelector = r.Next(1, 14);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Random` if provided by the **same seed**, always returns the **same sequence of numbers**. I suggest you initialise your Random using a seed:

```
            Random r = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
```

Or even better:

```
            Random r2 = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 0));
```

This ensures that you create a really random number sequence. If you do not send  a seed, system will use a time dependent seed which will be the same if you create them immediately after each other.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the first four bytes of a Guid are a good seed. And your first suggestion is exactly how the default constructor of `Random` currently works. And thus suffers from the same problem: the seed only changes every few milliseconds.

Comment: Should I mathematically prove that GUID is better?

Comment: A GUID generator only tries to achieve uniqueness. It doesn't guarantee a good distribution for parts of a GUID. While the current implementation of GUIDs on windows is indeed based on high quality random numbers there is no contractual obligation to remain like that. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Comment: It is not a question of whether GUID is unique.... it cannot be since it has a limitation (2 in power of 128, yet as you mentioned distribution is not even) which makes it only practically unique. But sure enough, while `Environment.TickCount` is  deterministic while GUID is not. A simple Monte Carlo experiment can prove how good this can be.

Comment: It will only show that for the current implementation of the GUID generator. Future versions of it may behave differently, just like past versions behaved differently. For example if you take the last 4 bytes of the GUID. Your experiment will show that they are random on the current version of windows. But if you try the same thing on an old version it's suddenly constant.